# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null. E/flutter (13701): Receiver: null E/flutter (13701): Tried calling: add

Tags: flutter, dart

I am sending non-null data to method. I shared my codes.

[image]

All parameter is non-null. I can see this  by printing. But when i add the my object to Map, I am getting this Error:

> E/flutter (13701): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.
> E/flutter (13701): Receiver: null
> E/flutter (13701): Tried calling: add(Instance of 'WorkHourData')
> E/flutter (13701): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
> E/flutter (13701): #1      DataController.groupBy. (package:working_hours/controller/data_controller.dart:30:39)
> E/flutter (13701): #2      ListMixin.forEach (dart:collection/list.dart:86:13)
> E/flutter (13701): #3      DataController.groupBy (package:working_hours/controller/data_controller.dart:18:37)
> E/flutter (13701): #4      _DetailPagesState.bottomNavigationButtons... (package:working_hours/view/pages/detail_page.dart:80:41)
> E/flutter (13701): #5      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1267:30)
> E/flutter (13701): #6      _DetailPagesState.bottomNavigationButtons.. (package:working_hours/view/pages/detail_page.dart:77:23)
> E/flutter (13701): #7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
> E/flutter (13701): #8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
> E/flutter (13701): #9      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:152:18)
> E/flutter (13701): #10     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:704:45)
> E/flutter (13701): #11     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:733:32)
> E/flutter (13701): #12     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:539:5)
> E/flutter (13701): #13     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:254:13)
> E/flutter (13701): #14     DatabaseHelper.getWorkingHours (package:working_hours/controller/db_controller.dart)
> E/flutter (13701): 
> E/flutter (13701):

Can you help me about this.
**

Comment: `Map` can return null value, so, you need to check that when you are get a value from `Map`, it is really exists.

Comment: @fartem, I looked dear friend. return value is not null.

Comment: Are you sure that `element["date"]` return something from Map?

Comment: it fixed. I initailized to list in map for every element.